# retrieve posted json data in webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am trying to upload some json data using ajax and retrieve in server side. I do get 'success' alert upon upload however unable to print the posted data. What am i doing wrong here?

```
var data = {
    "UserID" : 1,
    "Name" : "Sara"       
}

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "../somepage.aspx/ProcessRequest", 
   data: JSON.stringify(data),                              
   success: function (msg) {
      alert("Success");
   },
   error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
});
```

Server side:

```
[ScriptService]
public partial class uploadInspection : System.Web.UI.Page
{
[WebMethod]
public void ProcessRequest()
{
   var jsonString = String.Empty;
   var resp = String.Empty;

   HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
   using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream))
   {
      jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
   }
   var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Items>(jsonString);              


   this.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
   this.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   this.Response.Write(Items);

}

public class Items
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Print the posted data *where*? Your callback success is just showing the "Success" alert... you should do something with the received data...

Comment: @gusman i need to return 'Items' object and do something with it. But for now, i just wanted to populate the data to see if the data is being retrieved.

Comment: You already do this, "msg" in your success callback must have the response in it, in this case the Items class serialized.

Comment: @gusman well what i was trying to say was how come Response.Write(Items) wasn't displayed?

Comment: You are doing an ajax call, ajax is an asynchronous transfer operation intended to update portions of your page, is not the same as a plain GET request. if you want to display it you must present it in some way, with al alert, changing the content of a div or something else

Comment: A simple way is: add <div id="receivedContent"></div> somwhere in your page, then in your succes do: document.getElementById("receivedContent").innerText = JSON.stringify(msg);

Comment: everything returned is in `msg`. work with that in javascript, on the client (a la gusman). (depending how you deal with it, you might need to use `msg.d`).